# Multiple SDL windows with YUV Overlay

Tags: c, linux, sdl, x11

Does anyone know, how to create two Windows ans both should have an own YUV Overlay with the SDL 1.3 Library?

It is possible or do I try to use a wrong strategy?

If I tried the following source, i got an error message:
[!] can't create local overlay YUV display is only supported on the screen surface

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static bool running = true;
static SDL_Window* win_local;
static SDL_Window* win_remote;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

//    SDL_SetVideoMode

    if((SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0))
    {
        printf("[!] can't initialize SDL %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(!(win_local = SDL_CreateWindow("Local Video", 0, 0, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS)))
    {
        printf("[!] can't create Window %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);

    }

    if(!(win_remote = SDL_CreateWindow("Remote Video", 700, 0, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)))
    {
        printf("[!] can't create Window %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }


    SDL_Surface* surface_local; 
    SDL_Surface* surface_remote; 

    if(!(surface_local = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win_local)))
    {
        printf("[!] can't get local surface %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(!(surface_remote = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win_remote)))
    {
        printf("[!] can't get remote surface %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }

    SDL_Overlay* overlay_local;
    SDL_Overlay* overlay_remote;

    if(!(overlay_local = SDL_CreateYUVOverlay(640, 480, SDL_IYUV_OVERLAY, surface_local)))
    {
        printf("[!] can't create local overlay %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                exit(-1);
    }
//
//  if(!(overlay_remote = SDL_CreateYUVOverlay(640, 480, SDL_IYUV_OVERLAY, surface_remote)))
//  {
//      printf("[!] can't create remote overlay %s\n", SDL_GetError());
//                exit(-1);
//  }


    SDL_Event event;
    while(running)
    {

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    running = false;
                break;
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_Delay(20);
    }

    //SDL_FreeSurface(local);
    //SDL_FreeSurface(remote);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(win_local);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win_remote);
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_CreateYUVOverlay` doesn't work well with multiple windows, because it's not part of 1.3 API, it was left for reverse compatibility with SDL 1.2.

I see three possible solutions:

1. Call `SDL_CreateYUVOverlay` just after `SDL_CreateWindow` for each surface. You will probably avoid the error but I'm not sure if it will work correctly.
2. See how [SDL_CreateYUVOverlay is implemented using 1.3 API](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/50bf98210aae/src/SDL_compat.c#l1507) and do something similar.
3. Use OpenGL and shaders.